# Rails -- save date attribute in store field

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Profile class that stores serialized profile information for a user:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  store :data, accessors: [:name, :location, :dob], coder: JSON

  belongs_to :user
end
```

I dropped a date selector into my profile#edit form:

```
<%= f.input :dob, label: "Date of Birth", as: :date, order: [:month, :day, :year], include_blank: true, start_year: 1900 %>
```

That renders the form perfectly, but I'm getting a multi-attribute error when I submit:

```
ActiveRecord::MultiparameterAssignmentErrors in ProfilesController#update
1 error(s) on assignment of multiparameter attributes [error on assignment [8, 16, 1980] to dob (undefined method `klass' for nil:NilClass)]
```

How do I get Rails to realize that the `:dob` field is a date so that it accepts the multiparam attributes?

Comment: What format would you like the date to be stored in `:dob`?

Comment: Whatever format I need to store so that Rails can handle it easily.  I would guess yyyy-mm-dd.

Comment: Or possibly a serialized Date object?  I'm actually not sure what the difference would be in terms of the actual stored data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the params are being passed via the `params[:date][1i]` format.

If so, in your controller, convert it back to a date string before updating your record using something like:

```
params[:dob] = Date.parse( params[:dob].to_a.sort.collect{|c| c[1]}.join("-") )
```

if you don't need it in a date object, you can remove the `Date.parse` part.

To answer the question in the comments...

Keep in mind that `params[:dob]` contains another Hash:

```
{ '1i'=>'2013', '2i'=>'12', '3i'=>'31' }
```

So, the `to_a.sort` converts that Hash into an array of arrays, and because the order of a Hash cannot be guaranteed, the `sort` makes sure they are in the expected order, e.g:

```
[['1i', '2013'], ['2i', '12'], ['3i', '31']]
```

Then it's a simple matter of *collecting* the values and joining them with a '-' to return a string in the proper format for `Date.parse` to accept.  In this example, `2013-12-31`

Hopefully, that clears it up a bit.

Comment: That sets up the dob param correctly, but I'm still getting the multiparam error.  Do I need to unset the other params?

Comment: Generally speaking, yes.  Technically, if you're using strong parameters and don't have them in your params.permit list, they will be silently ignored.

Comment: I don't really understand why the sort call is in the middle of all that? Wouldn't 2013-04-05 be sorted and become 2013-05-04 for example?

Comment: Updated the answer with an explanation. :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to store the date in its component form?

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  store :data, accessors: [:name, :location, dob: [:month, :day, :year]], coder: JSON

  belongs_to :user
end
```